# add another class on several div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add another class on my divs by using javascript but it's not working. I have to call the class "olds" because I've several similar tables with div "mydiv" I don't want to change

here is the JS

```
$(".olds").next(tr).next(td).find(.mydiv).addclass("plop");
```

here is the HTML

```
<table>
  <tr><th><span class="olds">blaa</span></th></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

and here is what I want by using "addclass"

```
<table>
  <tr><th><span class="olds">blaa</span></th></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <div class="mydiv plop"></div>
    <div class="mydiv plop"></div>
    <div class="mydiv plop"></div>
    <div class="mydiv plop"></div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the correct syntax to add a class is `addClass()`

Comment: The next() method only works on *siblings* (and your "olds" element has no siblings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small error. It's `addClass` and not `addclass`. You also need to enclose the element names in quotation marks.

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

One solution is to traverse up the DOM by finding the closest table and then traversing down with the `find` method.

```js
$(".olds").closest("table").find(".mydiv").addClass("plop");
```

```css
.plop { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th><span class="olds">blaa</span></th></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <div class="mydiv">Div 1</div>
    <div class="mydiv">Div 2</div>
    <div class="mydiv">Div 3</div>
    <div class="mydiv">Div 4</div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS won't be able to find some of the objects as they will be null.
Try this one

```
$(".olds").next("tr").next("td").find(".fofo").addClass("plop");
```